# Calling a function in a included template file?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Hi I am kind new to jquery mobile and I am struggling with a problem. The basic structure of my web app is that I have a home page (index.php) with a button on it.  When the button is clicked it loads a second page (query.php). on that page a json feed gets pulled  in. (this page contains only php and no html or javascript). At the botom of the page this page includes a external template file (list.tmpl.php) which renders the feed that was pulled in by query.php.

I based this app on the following tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-build-an-rss-reader-with-jquery-mobile-2/  .Everything works as it should so far

Here comes my problem:
On the template page (list.tmpl.php) i placed a button which I want to use to call a simple javascript function. Somehow however I am not able to call that function. When I put the same function together with the button on the index.php it works and the script is executed.

I searched the net and found the following solution, which seems to come closest to a reasonable solution. 
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-equivalent-of-document-ready

However it did not work for me.  I am still not able to call the function. The query.php to which the button on index.php links to has no page id (no html just php) and the page in which I want to call  the function is the template (list.tmpl.php) which is included in this page. When I use the page id of the template page the function is not executed . 
Can anyone help?

Comment: Posting code would be helpful to diagnose the problem. If you could post the "button code" from `list.tmpl.php` and the "function code" from `index.php` we could probably help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the web app to do what I wanted. I realized that the problem I had has already been disussed quite a bit in various forums.

The problem was related to the fact that jQuery mobile only loads javascript functions till the DOM is ready and that it then only injects the content of other sites into the DOM and ignores the scripts for that page.

Based on the following tutorial I was able to understand how jQuery mobile loads javascript much better. I suggest it to anyone who struggles with the same problem:

[atozdotnet.com: jQuery Mobile - Ajax - Dynamic content - Passing parameters (based on A4.1)](http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=196)